# Get pdf File from SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, pdf, blob

I'm trying to restore some datafiles (mostly pdfs) from a SQL Server base.

[image: Image column type]

The table column  is of the following type: D_BLOB(image) and contains this type of data: 
[image]

As for the code and different approaches I tried, here my different parts of code combined

```
byte[] output = qResult.getBytes("DOCUMENT");
Blob blob = qResult.getBlob("DOCUMENT");
String document2 = qResult.getString("DOCUMENT");

InputStream input = qResult.getBinaryStream("DOCUMENT");
FileOutputStream output2 = new FileOutputStream(new File(repertoireDst +     "\\" + intitule + "_test2_." + extension));
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (input.read(buffer) > 0) {
            output2.write(buffer);
            }
output2.close();

/************************************
 * Simple input output Stream
 *******************/
InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(repertoireDst + "\\" + intitule + "_test_." + extension);

int bytesRead = -1;
byte[] buffer2 = new byte[1024];
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer2)) != -1) {
outputStream.write(buffer2, 0, bytesRead);
}

inputStream.close();
outputStream.close();

/************************************
 * Simple byte writing
 *******************/
FileOutputStream fos = null;

fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(repertoireDst + "\\" + intitule + "_V1_EcritureBytesSymple." + extension));
fos.write(output);
fos.flush();
fos.close();

/*************************************************
 * Ecriture of bynary stream from blob
 ***********************************************/
InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();
FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(repertoireDst + "\\" + intitule + "_V2_BlobEcritDirectement.txt");

int b = 0;
while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
fos1.write(b);
}
fos1.flush();
fos1.close();
/**************************************************************************
 * Testing for base 64 encoding
 ************************************************************************/

File fichierDestinationTemp = new File(repertoireDst + "\\" + intitule + "_V3_FichierTxtTemp.txt");
File fichierDestinationTemp2 = new File(repertoireDst + "\\" + intitule + "_V4_FichierEncoderDecoder.txt");
File fichierDestinationTemp3 = new File(repertoireDst + "\\" + intitule + "_V5_FichierEncoder." + extension);
```

File fichierDestination = new File(repertoireDst + "\" + intitule + "." + extension);

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fichierDestinationTemp, "Cp1252");
writer.print(document2);
writer.close();

byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(output);
String encodedString = new String(encodedBytes);

FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(fichierDestinationTemp3);
fos2.write(encodedString.getBytes());
fos2.flush();
fos2.close();

byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
FileOutputStream fos3 = new FileOutputStream(fichierDestinationTemp2);
fos3.write(decodedBytes);
fos3.flush();
fos3.close();
```

Of course this creates my all sort of files, but non of the pdf files is readable. I guess I miss something. (And yeah I know that some parts I'm writing into .txt files but this was to see what I would get and hey, some of them where even in chinse...)

[image: text file in chinese]

Any idea is welcome, wondering what I'm missing.

Comment: If the files *were* pdf files before, why do you think they would be readable in notepad? Of course it's going to look like a bunch of random characters, as the application has no idea how to read the binary file. On a different note, why are you still using `image`? It's been deprecated since at least SQL Server 2005.

Comment: These aren't PDF files. If there were, your blob contents would start with `0x25504446`.

Comment: I only try to open them in notepad to see what the base64 encoding does to them. (To compare the strings). Normally I open PDF files in my browser. Also, I'm not the one having created this database, so I can't really change the fact that they are unsing image. Also thanks to Andrey Nilolov, I guess there must be some kind of encoding/compressing beeing used then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what type of data was stored, the 0x78 is corresponding to zlib 4.0. This means I was able to inflate the data with an InflateOutputStream in java. Then I just had to save the data with a .pdf extension and everything was fine afterwards.